# How to fix "The CMAKE_C_COMPILER: cl is not a full path and was not found in the PATH." error on jupyter notebook

Tags: python, windows, cmake, jupyter-notebook

While installing nervana [aeon](https://github.com/NervanaSystems/aeon) on jupyter notebook, I run following commands for Python 3.n:

```
cd aeon
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
mkdir -p build && cd $_ && cmake .. && pip3 install
```

the last command throws the error mentioned below:

```
The CXX compiler identification is unknown
Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/MOMNAH/Desktop/anaconda/ArtGAN-master/ArtGAN/aeon/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/MOMNAH/Desktop/anaconda/ArtGAN-master/ArtGAN/aeon/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:22 (project):
  The CMAKE_C_COMPILER: cl is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.

  To use the NMake generator with Visual C++, cmake must be run from a shell
  that can use the compiler cl from the command line.  This environment is
  unable to invoke the cl compiler.  To fix this problem, run cmake from the
  Visual Studio Command Prompt (vcvarsall.bat).

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full path to
  the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:22 (project):
  The CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:

    clang++

  is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.

  To use the NMake generator with Visual C++, cmake must be run from a shell
  that can use the compiler cl from the command line.  This environment is
  unable to invoke the cl compiler.  To fix this problem, run cmake from the
  Visual Studio Command Prompt (vcvarsall.bat).

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the full path
  to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.
```

Comment: Do you have a Clang installation? Is it in your `%PATH%`? Alternatively, do you have a Visual Studio (full, or build tools) installation?

Comment: I have visual studio installation,what is the proper way to set its path ?

Comment: See [the documentation](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers) Also make sure you actually install EITHER the Visual Studio build tools OR (VS2019 AND the C/C++ workload)

Comment: Sorry I just realized you were invoking cmake directly. Then putting the tools on your path is best done according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/building-on-the-command-line?view=vs-2019 . Alternatively you can use the visual studio specific generator for cmake, that will find a visual studio installation by itself.